# How integrate firebase in my React Project?

Tags: reactjs

https://github.com/ModestasZauka/React-E-Shop

How integrate firebase in my  React Project ?

Comment: You should probably add some more information about what exactly you want to do,

Answer (score 0):

Heyy this is the first result of my google search 
https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial